# Recover a git repo which was overwritten with an older version

Tags: git, data-recovery

I've just run `tar x` by mistake instead of `tar c`, and overwrote my git repo with a few days older version.  This will have left alone any files I had newly created though, including objects in `.git`.  How can I recover as much as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of the whole mess first, just in case.

`git fsck` will show dangling objects and commits.  Find the newest dangling commit.  I fed all the commit hashes to `gitk`, and it just shows the most "recent" one at the top.  As well as only having a few commits to deal with, I only had a single branch to recover - this would be more complex if there was more than one head.

Then `git stash` to stash currently uncommitted changes for inspection.

I was then able to `git reset --hard` to the commit hash determined above.

`git stash pop` also merged back pretty cleanly.  I think I got pretty much everything I wanted back again.

Comment: If you didn't do anything "clever" between the backup point and the restore point all commits should be already there, you might be able to get away with just moving HEAD.  You'll lose some of the changes not already committed though.

Comment: That's what I did with the `git reset --hard HASH` command.  The real trick is the bit before that, finding the hash of the commit you want to move to.